# How to compare an input string using if statement

Tags: python

I am giving an input, that gets stored in the variable "inp". When I compare it in the if condition shown below, I am not getting the right output. The for loop is executed, but no output is shown. When I replace the variable by string "bin_A", I am getting the right output.

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
def main():
    with open("apc.json") as data_file:
      data = json.load(data_file)

    inp = raw_input("enter name") 
    print "read the input", str(inp)   
    for i in range(0,12):

      if data["work_order"][i]["bin"] == inp :  #have tried repr(inp)
          print data["work_order"][i]["bin"]
          print "gotcha", i
          print data["work_order"][i]["item"]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note:
Output of `print data["work_order"][i]["bin"]` is Bin_A. So, when I try to give my input as Bin_A, nothing happens

Comment: Maybe you should show what is in data[work_order][i][bin]?

Comment: what is the type of data `data["work_order"][i]["bin"]`?? if is not str, then they never will be equals., Also try `str(data[...])` given that the print is as you say...

Answer (score 2):

Considering `data` was set from

```
data = json.load(data_file)
```

Then you probably need to convert the variable `i` from an `int` to a `str`

```
if data["work_order"][str(i)]["bin"] == inp
```

Or since you seem to use `i` multiple times, you could directly say

```
for i in map(str, range(0,12)):
```

Comment: conversion [str(i)] doesn't seem to work as well. But, could you please explain the reason for conversion ?

Comment: Perhaps `str(data["work_order"][i]["bin"])`, if otherwise an object is returned?